# How to fill color inside of checkbox in flutter?

Tags: flutter, checkbox, flutter-layout, flutter-theme

Here is what I am using for checkbox in flutter.
But I can set only border color for unchecked state, not method found for fill color inside of the checkbox.
Please help me with this.

```
Theme(
    data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white),
    child: Checkbox(
        checkColor: Colors.blue,
        activeColor: Colors.white,
        value: rememberMe,
        onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
                rememberMe = value;
            });
        },
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is more related to design itself. An empty checkbox should be exactly that, empty. If you give it a fill color, you are kind of defeating the design purpose.

Regardless, you could achieve this by putting it inside a `Container` with a background color and the width and height to only fill the `CheckBox`:

```
return Center(
  child: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    width: 14,
    height: 14,
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: Checkbox(
      checkColor: Colors.blue,
      activeColor: Colors.white,
      value: rememberMe,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          rememberMe = value;
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: While this works, it makes clickable bounds of the CheckBox way too small to be accessible.

Comment: Adjust the height and weight of the parent container @Niko

Comment: This is a hack. Is there really no clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes have a property called fillColor

From the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox/fillColor.html), here is how to use it

```
Checkbox(
  value: true,
  onChanged: (_){},
  fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>((Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
      return Colors.orange.withOpacity(.32);
    }
    return Colors.orange;
  })
)
```